# Avoid callback multi-invocation when forEach is used

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise

I have a function that processes an array of data (first parameter) and, once the procesing is finished, it invokes *only one time* a callback function (second parameter). I'm using `forEach` to process data item by item, consisting the processing of each item in some checkings and storing the param in database. The function `storeInDB()` does the storing work and uses a callback (second parameter) when the item has been stored.

A first approach to the code is the following:

```
function doWork(data, callback) {
    data.forEach(function (item) {
        // Do some check on item
        ...
        storeInDB(item, function(err) {
           // check error etc.
           ...
           callback();
        });
    });
}
```

However, it's wrong, as the the `callback` function will be invoked several times (as many as element in the `data` array).

I'd like to know how to refactor my code in order to achieve the desired behaviour, i.e. only one invocation to `callback` once the storing work is finished. I guess that [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/) could help in this task, but I haven't find the right pattern yet to combine async + forEach.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library such as `async` to do this, although I would recommend using promises if possible. For your immediate problem you can use a counter to determine how many storage calls have completed and call the callback when the total number are completed.

```
let counter = 0;
data.forEach(function (item) {
    // Do some check on item
    ...
    storeInDB(item, function(err) {
       // check error etc.
       counter++
       if (counter == data.length) {
         callback();
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If `storeInDB` function returns a promise, you can push all async functions to an array and use **Promise.all**. After all tasks run successfully, It will invokes callback function.

Hope this helps you.

```
function doWork(data, callback) {
  let arr = [];
  data.map(function(itm) {
    // Do some check on item
    ...
    arr.push(storeInDB(item));
  });
  Promise.all(arr)
    .then(function(res) {
      callback();
    });
}
```

Comment: You should not use `forEach` in this case (and any other case, btw) but use `map` instead

Comment: When storeInDB has a callback, it does not mean it returns a promise? @Bergi

Comment: If it takes a callback, that usually means that it *does not* return a promise.

Comment: Hmmm, Good tip, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can also utilize the three parameters passed to the function to execute on each array method

```
function doWork(data, callback) {

    data.forEach(function (value,idx,arr) {
        // Do some check on item
        ...
        storeInDB(arr[idx], function(err) {
            // check error etc.
            ...
            if ( (idx + 1) === arr.length ) {
                callback();
            }
        });
    });
 }
```